# How can I install a specific version of laravel?

Tags: windows, installation, php

I've been handed over an application that is based off laravel.. however it's made in a previous version of laravel (3).. and the current laravel version is 4.. is there a way to install a specific version of laravel? there is no mention of that in the laravel [website](http://laravel.com/docs/installation)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Laravel the application was developed in should be defined in the applications `composer.json` file under the `"require"` section.

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
},
```

Composer will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Installation of Laravel Current Version (may be 5.4 or 5.5 or whatever)

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name
```

Installation of Laravel Previous Version (may be 5.3)

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 5.3.*
```

Installation of Laravel Previous Version (may be 5.2)

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 5.2.*
```

Installation of Laravel Previous Version (may be 5.1)

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 5.1.*
```

Installation of Laravel Previous Version (may be 5.0)

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 5.0.*
```

Installation of Laravel Previous Version (may be 4.2)

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 4.2.*
```

What about installing upcoming versions? Well, as usually upcoming version is put into dev-develop branch, all we do to pass this branch name again:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name dev-develop
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to mentioned in composer.json file which you want to download. foreg:"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*"
},